# Relation between: Likelihood, conditional probability and failure rate

Tags: probability, probability-theory

My question is about the possibility of showing equivalence between the hazard rate, the conditional probability (of failure) and a likelihood function.

---

**Dynamics:**

Consider a coin that has $P(\boldsymbol{H})=p$ and $P(\boldsymbol{T})=1-p$ such that $P(H) + P(T) = 1$. The stochastic process $X(t)$ evolves according to this dynamic over time $t$ resulting in a series of $\boldsymbol{H}$ until at time $T$ it lands on tails $\boldsymbol{T}$ which ends the sequence.

---

**Definitions:**

- Consider $T$ a continuous random variable with density $f(t)$ and cumulative density $F(t)$.

1) **Hazard rate**: $\mu(t)=\frac{f(t)}{1-F(t)}$.

Aka. force of mortality, hazard function, failure rate, [see wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis). This can be larger than one.

2) **Conditional probability of failure:** $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)=\frac{P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t)\cap P(T>t)}{P(T>t)}\approx\mu(t)\triangle t$

Showing equivalence between 1) and 2) for $\triangle t\rightarrow0$ is easy. Again, see wiki. 2) is the *conditional probability of failure*, given that the unit worked up until time $t$.

3) **Likelihood function:** $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X)$.

Where $\theta$ is a parameter ($p$) and $X$ is the data observed (e.g. the series of H). E.g. assuming a fair coin we can write $\mathcal{L}(P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5|\boldsymbol{HH})=P(\boldsymbol{HH}|P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5)=0.25$. Or alternatively, $P(\boldsymbol{T}|\boldsymbol{HH})=1-P(\boldsymbol{HH}|P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5)=0.75.$

---

**Questions:**

**q. 1**) Am I right in asserting that the likelihood function $\mathcal{L}(\theta|X)$ $is$ the complement to the conditional probability function  $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t)$?

Exemplified as $P(\boldsymbol{T}|\boldsymbol{HH})=1-P(\boldsymbol{HH}|P(\boldsymbol{H})=0.5)=0.75.$

**q. 1.2**) If **q .1** is true, how is the likelihood function connected to the hazard rate function? Can they be shown to be equivalent?

**q. 1.3**) Intuitively, all conditional probabilities are purely multiplicative processes. Can we generally write this as $P(t<T\leq t+\triangle t|T\geq t) = 1-\prod^{t+\triangle t}_tP(\boldsymbol{H})_t$? E.g. as the *conditional* probability of realising another $\boldsymbol{H}$ decreases, the probability (and thus likelihood?) of realising $\boldsymbol{T}$ increases.

**q. 2**) Is it generally true, that if all conditional probablities are purely multiplicative processes of numbers between one and zero, they *all* decrease with some exponential rate $\lambda$?

Consider the **cumulative hazard rate**: $\varGamma=\int_0^t\mu(u)du=-log(1-F(t))$. See [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).

**q. 2.1**) If **q. 2** is correct, and we can express the integral over hazard rate as the negative logarithm to the complement of the cdf $-log(1-F(t)$ (sometimes called the survival function), is this essentially the same as the conditional probability?

**q. 3**) How does the above relate to the notion of *sojourn time*? One can imagine $N$ states with $N$ different hazard rates. What is this problem generally called and how can I relate it to expected mean sojourn time? Intuitively, states with a high hazard rate will have lower sojorn time. Are these equivalent somehow?

**q. 4**) If anyone would care to relate this to a Markov Chain with absorbing states, they are most welcome. Especially I am interested in how the conditinal probability relates to the transition probabilities.

---

I realise these are a lot of questions. Any hints, partial answers or call for clarity is appreciated, thanks!

---

[Crosspost to stats.stackexchange.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249031/relation-between-likelihood-conditional-probability-and-failure-rate)